# Sides of non-right triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given a non-right triangle with vertex $C = 91^{\circ}, \
> \overline{AC} =39.9 \ cm, \ \overline{BC} = 32.6 \ cm$, find
>
> a) $\overline{AB}$
>
> b) $m\measuredangle A$
>
> c) $m\measuredangle B$

I was able to find the length of $\overline{AB}$, which I labeled $c$
\begin{align*} c=& \ \sqrt{32.6^2+39.9^2-2(32.6*39.9)\cos(91^\circ)}
\\ c =& \ 51.9 \ cm
\end{align*}

but I'm having a hard time finding the angle measures of $A$ and $B$,
here's my attempt:

a)
\begin{align*} \frac{32.6}{\sin A} =& \frac{51.9}{\sin 91^\circ} \\ \\ \sin A =& \frac{32.6 \sin 91^\circ}{51.9} \\
\end{align*}
So given some theta A, we get the vertical length $0.63$ radians. To find A, I used
\begin{align*} \arcsin (0.63) \approx 0.68 \ \text{rad}
\end{align*}
So I figured I just needed to convert this to degree measure, getting me  $$m\measuredangle A \approx 38.96^\circ$$

b) using the fact that the sum of angle measures of a triangle is $180^\circ$, I tried to solve for angle $B$ using 
\begin{align*} 38.96^\circ + 51.9^\circ + m\measuredangle B \approx& \ 180^\circ \\ m\measuredangle B \approx& \ 89.14^\circ
\end{align*}

but I'm getting marked wrong for both answers b) and c). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since you’ve found the first result correct as c=51.9, it seems the approximation is to truncate. If that is the case, then the value for angle A that you’ve got as 38.96 can not be correct because you can not obtain a 4-digit precision using numbers in 3-digit precision. Should be either 38.8 or 38.9. Then third angle is deducted by difference from 180.

Answer (score 1):

Side length $c \approx 51.9$ is ok.

The triangle side lengths are close to the right triangle of sides $ 30,40,50$  in proportion.

$$ \angle A ( \approx 38.96^{\circ})+ \angle B^{\circ} + 91 ^{\circ} = 180^{\circ}\rightarrow \angle B\approx 50.04 ^{\circ} $$

Comment: You are mixing the 4-digit precision of the angle A to obtain a 3-digit precision of the angle B. However, using your numbers the answer is 50.04 and you approximate that to 50.2

Comment: Thanks, shall change it. Only indicated the single step required.

Answer (score 0):

On the last answer you are using 51.9, which is the length of side c, instead of the correct value of 91 degrees.
As for calculating the angle A, I am guessing that it is marked wrong because of an insufficient explanation. You indeed show that $sin(A) = 0.63$, but this does not always imply that $ A = 38.96 $ degrees.